# Why Atom Z2760 won't boot live GNU/Linux

Tags: linux, uefi, live-usb

I'm trying to install any GNU/Linux distribution (Debian, Archlinux, Ubuntu...) on Acer Iconia Tab W510, with 32bits UEFI and [Atom Z2760 processor](https://www.intel.fr/content/www/fr/fr/products/sku/70105/intel-atom-processor-z2760-1m-cache-1-80-ghz/specifications.html).
After preparing the ISO with correct EFI files ([as explained here](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1804211&sid=9e97b338c5d03cdd0127252a3d3e0cc6#p1804211)), the tablet shows GRUB menu or commandline, but I can't get it to boot Linux.
There are no error messages, just a black screen (I try to wait 1h+ but nothing happens)
Secure boot is already disabled, I tried with more than 10 different ISOs, with or without adding EFI files, different kernel arguments, etc.

*How would this tablet prevent Linux from booting? What could I try to understand and fix the problem?*

**EDIT:** of course, I tried a lot of different ISO, `x86_64` *AND* `i686`/`i386`, in particular:

- debian-12.4.0-i386-netinst.iso
- archlinux32-2023.03.02-i686.iso
- trisquel-mini_9.0.1_i686.iso
- xubuntu-18.04.5-desktop-i386.iso

I also tried multiple different USB sticks, which I flash with `dd` (as usual). I also tried same ISOs and same USB drives but this time using ([Ventoy](https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html)). All my tries lead to the same result: **black screen after vmlinuz and initrd are loaded from GRUB.**

Comment: Perhaps all those iso's expect the cpu to be 64bit, not 32bit. You need to download & burn a 32bit specific installation media. It needs more than just the UEFI to be 32bit.

Comment: As above, indeed. You've tried to follow instructions for those "frankenstein" low-cost Intel systems from ~2013 with 64-bit Atom CPUs coupled with 32-bit UEFI. **But the Intel Atom® Z2760  is actually 32-bit**, your own link says so: ***Jeux d'instructions 32-bit***. You can't use any 64-bit distro, you must use one from  the rapidly dwindling 32-bit  distros list, like Debian.

Comment: Yes, I know that it requires a 32bits kernel. I forgot to mention it, see the EDIT

Comment: It would have been a vastly more useful edit if you posted what you tried (except the 64-bit ones because all of that was a waste of time). What 32-bit distros **and releases/versions** you tried is what matters because some were probably too old and shouldn't be used anyway. Also exactly how did you made the live/installation media.